# angular JavaScript de-structuring issue in the function

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular for my project. please check the below function and result

Function

```
    registerLocker({ branchCode, lockerCode }) {
    let item =  { branchCode, lockerCode };
}
```

Result

[image]

My expected result is as below

```
  {"reserve":{"branchCode":"B001","lockerCode":"L01"}}
```

how i change my function for do get above result

Comment: This has nothing to do with destructuring

Comment: Very simple thing. `let item = { "reserve" : { branchCode, lockerCode } };`

Answer (score 0):

We can do that like below:
Hope it works!

```
let item = {
    reserve: {
       "branchCode":"B001","lockerCode":"L01"
    }
}
```